# Tizen xamarin webview app closes on launch

Tags: c#, xamarin, tizen

I'm trying to create a C# Xamarin project for tizen TV
Whenever I include WebView control the app launches then immediately closes.

I have set internet on privileges (and more) but the same thing happens all the time. However when I try with other controls (label, button) it works just fine.
``

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CrossTemplate
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            var html = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = "your html here"
            };
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new ContentPage
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Children = {
                        new WebView
                        {
                            WidthRequest = 100,
                            HeightRequest = 100,
                            /* Source = "http://google.com/" Url or pure html same thing happens*/
                            Source = html
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At first, you should change `Source = html` to `Source = html.Html`, then please run this code in your mobile phone If this app will close. If it close, you can check the output from debug, and post the information of output here.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this page](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-reference/.net-application/current-xamarin.forms-limitations).

You can not use a webview on the Tizen TV platform.